# Dask-ssh with local scheduler?

Tags: ssh, dask, dask-ssh

I would like to use dask-ssh to automatically load up worker nodes on a set of remote IP addresses. However, I would like the worker nodes to connect to a local scheduler. From the [docs page](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup/ssh.html), I wasn't quite sure how to accomplish this.

My specific questions are as follows:

1. Is this supported by dask-ssh?
2. If so, do I provide my local IP address into dask-ssh? e.g.:

```
$ dask-ssh --scheduler <my.ip.addr.here> <other.ip.addresses.here>
```

Comment: So long as you can ssh to your local machine, I would expect it to work. Did you try?

Comment: I did try, but I didn't think about ssh-ing into my local machine. Thank you for the tip!

Comment: Hmmm..... Looks like I'm not able to SSH into my local machine from my local machine. Company computer seems to have a bunch of settings disabled, e.g. I cannot restart firewall, cannot open this/that port etc. Thanks @mdurant for the pingback nonetheless, appreciated!

Comment: If you come up with the correct set of firewall settings, you may want to make your question more specific to your situation, then post and accept your own answer

Answer (score 1):

As of 2019-01-30 this is not supported, but is definitely in-scope.  It would be a nice contribution.

Comment: do you mean 2019? ;)

Comment: Fixed.  Thanks @ericmjl